# Can I create many hooks in react dynamically?

Tags: reactjs

Here's the problem...

I would like a way to dynamically create hooks from an object. The actual state and setState function should be named dynamically also, and the initial value should be set via the object also.

Below is some pseudocode that shows what I'm trying to do (eval should not be used for this). The bigger picture is simply creating various view components and animating between them. If there were 100 views, however, my jsx would look awfully long. Each component needs to know who is before and after it so it can animate properly and they all need some state so they can know when to enter and exit.

If there's a good way to do this please let me know. I'm also open to tangental solutions because this probably isn't the best way to do this.

```
const User = ({...props}) => {

  const views = {
    "Instructions": true,
    "Sort": false,
    "Evaluation": false,
    ...
  };

  Object.entries(views).map(([columnId, val], index) => {
    eval("const [phase" + columnId +", set" + columnId + "] = useState(" + val + ")");
  })

  return <>
    ...
```

Comment: instead try using array and then push object `{columnId, val}` in array. Put this array in state, you can use array inside your component.

Comment: This will not solve your problem. You will need to write a component and use that. Eval would be executed only when the component is being initiated, and not at transpile time

Comment: how would you use these variables?

Comment: With the csstransition component to set a state to false with button (which begins css transition exit) and then there's an onExited where I can set a different view state to true @lissettdm

Comment: If anyone sees this in the future... simply use two states and set the nextState to the view you want to navigate to and the currentState to null (which begins an animation out) then on the onExited handler, simply set the current state to the nextState... this makes it super easy to animate between CSSTransition components. This doesn't not solve creating hooks dynamically, but solves the larger issue I had.

Comment: @BenjaminHobson Click the "Answer your own question" button and give a code example please?